# Wordpress header file missing

Tags: wordpress, header

I'm used to working on wordpress sites with header, footer, etc files. Recently i set up a wordpress website using the theme ascension. But when i checked "Appearances > Editor", there is no header or footer file. Why is it missing? How do i add codes within the head tags if there is no header file?

I read somewhere that i need to add a certain code on the function file to make them appear but it didn't really work and I didn't really understand the process. Can anybody shed light on this? I'm not really techy so pls keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those files appearing in FTP?

Comment: Try with FTP. It's not a good idea to edit files from Dashboard.

Comment: You may be using a child theme of ascension.  Inherited templates don't show up.

Comment: I already checked via FTP but there are no header or footer files there either. I'm also not using a child theme. But Ascension theme has a parent theme which is Primer and the site went down when I tried to delete Primer. That actually makes it even more confusing now. If I get to creating a child theme, what theme would I base it on - ascension or primer? But yeah that's a different issue.